# Restoring Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, backup

My laptop's hard drive broke down recently, and I had to replace it. Before it broke, it was running Windows 8, and I was trying to set it up to dual boot with Ubuntu. But every time I ran the Ubuntu installer, it would crash while trying to install Grub. So I thought, since my new hard drive is empty anyway, maybe I should try installing Ubuntu first and then restore Windows 8 from my backup afterward, since I've heard that Ubuntu is easier to set up dual boot with than Windows. But I've never had to use Windows' backup tools before, so I'm not sure if that would work; I'm kinda scared that when Windows sees another OS on the hard drive, it'll either go bonkers or try to overwrite it. Does anyone know if it's possible to restore a backup after installing another OS like this?

The backup of Windows itself is a copy of the recovery partition that came with the laptop, and for the backup of my files I used the Windows 7 recovery tools. My laptop is an Asus UX302L.

Thanks

Comment: Windows is so lame, it doesn't 'see', nor care about any other operating system. Windows is completely oblivious of linux partitions, it will mark them as 'unknown format'. Windows is like a medieval catholic, it will suggest you to reformat any partition that it doesn't recognize and understand. Just burn the witch! Destroy the 'unholy'! But **you** have to 'do' that (manually), it will not automatically reformat anything without your consent.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring Windows from one PC to another is ... a Windows problem, not Ubuntu problem. I guess it can be done. This site does not offer Windows support. Perhaps you should looks for such backup support on Windows sites.

As for dual-boot, i always find easier to first install/restore Windows and then install Ubuntu. Less trouble, less problems (Ubuntu recognize Win OS, but WinOS doesn't recognize Ubuntu, etc).